# Find the duplicates in java arraylist

Tags: java

I have an arraylist looks like this

```
[week=Mon May 19 00:00:00 EST 2014, projectID=21793, hours=1.5, defaultWorkType=Ps]
```

I wanted to filter all the values which are dulicated on projectID and week fields
and find the sum of the hrs.

```
for an eg:
 [week=Mon May 19 00:00:00 EST 2014, projectID=21793, hours=1, defaultWorkType=Ps]
 [week=Mon May 19 00:00:00 EST 2014, projectID=21793, hours=3, defaultWorkType=Ps]
 [week=Mon May 19 00:00:00 EST 2014, projectID=21793, hours=2, defaultWorkType=Ps]
```

So the answer should be this,

```
[week=Mon May 19 00:00:00 EST 2014, projectID=21793, hours=6, defaultWorkType=Ps]
```

private List findTotalPSHrs(List filteredPS){

```
    List<PreSale> li = new ArrayList<PreSale>();

    for(Integer i=0 ; i<filteredPS.size();i++)
    {
        Integer x=0;
        while(x<filteredPS.size()){
            if(filteredPS.get(i)==filteredPS.get(x++)){
                li.add(filteredPS.get(i));
                System.out.println("--------------------------"+filteredPS.get(i));
                System.out.println("*** "+ filteredPS.get(x++));
            }
        }
    }

    return filteredPS;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What should the output be for: `[week=Mon May 19 00:00:00 EST 2014, projectID=21793, hours=1, defaultWorkType=A]
 [week=Mon May 19 00:00:00 EST 2014, projectID=21793, hours=3, defaultWorkType=B]` ?

Comment: What's stored in the arraylist? string? user-defined object?

Comment: your javascript array decelerations is totally incorrect

Comment: try putting them in set and before putting them just check whether they already are present in the set

Comment: @ali-shahrokhi it is a Java ArrayList, not a JavaScript Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the array list and add "project" + "week"to a hash map where the value is the hours.  If the key already exists, just update the hours.  The hash map will then contain the info you need to generate your desired output.

Perhaps something like this:

```
private List<PreSale> findTotalPSHrs(List<PreSale> data) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> cumulative = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (PreSale item : data) {
        String key = item.getWeek() + "," + item.getProjectID().toString();
        if (cumulative.containsKey(key)) {
            cumulative.put(key, cumulative.get(key) + data.getHours());
        } else {
            cumulative.put(key, data.getHours());
        }
    }

    // at this point, cumulative contains a single entry for each project/week with
    // the cumulative hours.  Now we need to convert that into your output list.

    List<PreSale> returnList = new ArrayList<PreSale>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : cumulative.entrySet()) {
        // "<week>,<project>"
        String[] parts = entry.getKey().split(",");
        PreSale saleObj = new PreSale();
        saleObj.setWeek(parts[0]);
        saleObj.setProject(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
        saleObj.setHours(entry.getValue());
        returnList.add(saleObj);
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

This may be a bit overkill, but it's the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: That sounds great to me. I'm just a fresher for java. Any clue how can I do that? I didn't know that I can have 2keys on hash map.